# coherence does not backup entries when using putall

Tags: caching, in-memory-database, oracle-coherence

I use coherence for caching some data. The cache is partitioned, off-heap and configured to backup entries on one another node.  So when i have 2 nodes and close one of them, cache size must not decrease and data on closed node must be recovered from backup. this scenario is Ok when i use namedcache.put method to adding entries to cache. My problem is that when i use namedcache.putall, entries dont backed up and when i close one node, entries on that node removed from cache.

**Update 1 :** This problem exist when using off-heap mode. In heap mode, no problem exist.

Used cache scheme is as following:

```
<distributed-scheme>
    <scheme-name>history-map</scheme-name>
    <service-name>HistoryMap</service-name>
    <serializer>
        <instance>
            <class-name>com.tangosol.io.pof.ConfigurablePofContext</class-name>
            <init-params>
                <init-param>
                    <param-type>String</param-type>
                    <param-value>pof-config.xml</param-value>
                </init-param>
            </init-params>
        </instance>
    </serializer>

    <thread-count>10</thread-count>
    <local-storage>true</local-storage>
    <partition-count>100</partition-count>
    <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    <backup-storage>
        <type>off-heap</type>
        <initial-size>1MB</initial-size>
        <maximum-size>50MB</maximum-size>
    </backup-storage>

    <backing-map-scheme>
        <partitioned>true</partitioned>
        <external-scheme>
            <nio-memory-manager>
                <initial-size>1MB</initial-size> 
                <maximum-size>50MB</maximum-size>
            </nio-memory-manager>
            <high-units>125</high-units>
            <unit-calculator>BINARY</unit-calculator>
            <unit-factor>1048576</unit-factor>
        </external-scheme>
    </backing-map-scheme>           
    <autostart>true</autostart>         
</distributed-scheme>
```

Comment: It is probably reaching the units limits? If yes, so the cache is cleaning the old entries for backup the new only. Check that.

Comment: @Samuelens, I check it. The problem still exist. I test it with only 100 entry (each entry about 200 byte). In all cases, when i use NamedCache.put everything is OK. Should i define high unit for backup separately or defined high unit for primary storage is used for backup too?

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand what did you test. I will give an example: define 100 units as a max size of the cache. Put, i.e. 20 units, and cause the failover (just kill one server). What happens? It should work...

Comment: I tested this scenario and problem still exist. I see different functionality using put or putall in this scenario..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem, and have created a bug for the issue.  We have a bug in populating backingMapEvent for SerializationMap which cause entries not being correctly backed up
The problem should be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using Coherence 3.7 or later, you should use the "Elastic Data" feature instead of NIO. It has most if not all of the same benefits, but is much faster and has higher density, and is easier to configure and use.
2. The backing map itself is not supposed to affect the processing of backups, so it is unclear to me why you would see the type of issue that you are describing. What version of Coherence are you running?

Comment: I am using coherence 12.1.2. what do you mean exactly from "Elastic data" feature? Does it need SSD storage?

Comment: 1.I am using coherence 12.1.2 and because of huge data caching (cache size is about 30GB) I have some problem with GC. what do you mean exactly from "Elastic data" feature? Does it need SSD storage? 2.I test it many times. Used configuration is in question text (above). I ran two nodes and put for example 100 entry on cache. then closed one of the nodes. Every time i used put method with a loop, all entries were recovered on live node, but when i used putall , data on closed node, lost. (I wrote another comment because i could not edit previous comment)

Comment: If you are using 12.1.2, then you should be using Elastic Data instead. See: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHDG/cache_back.htm#BJFEEBCB (The feature you are using will likely be deprecated in 12.1.3 or 12.1.4; the preferred replacement feature is Elastic Data.) Regarding the putAll(), it is not clear to me why it doesn't work for you, unless there is something screwy in your config. Regarding SSD, it is optional for Elastic Data (but nice to have!); if you're sizing such that you are not expecting to overflow to disk, then using a spinning drive as an overflow is OK too.